# Join two model to present in a view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to join two below model class with entity framework in controller for present factor in accounting system in a view

```
<pre>
namespace AccountingSystem.Models
{
    public class BuyFactor
    {
        public int BuyFactorId { get; set; }        
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }        
        public string Seller { get; set; }
        public string Creator { get; set; }
        public decimal SumAllPrice { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BuyFactorDetail> BuyFactorDetails { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AccountingSystem.Models
{
    public class BuyFactorDetail
    {
        public int BuyFactorDetailId { get; set; }         
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal SumPrice { get; set; }
        public int BuyFactorId { get; set; }
        public virtual BuyFactor BuyFactor { get; set; }        
        public virtual Commodity Commodity { get; set; }        
    }
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Model

```
public class JointModel
{
   public BuyFactor BuyFactor {get; set;}
   public BuyFactorDetail BuyFactorDetail {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create another model then calls the other model in there

```
 public class ParentModel
 {
 public BuyFactor BuyFactor {get; set;}
 public BuyFactorDetail BuyFactorDetail {get; set;}
 }
```

So when you will call it in view

```
 @model IEnumerable<AccountingSystem.Models.ParentModel>

   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BuyFactor.Creator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way define `Model` as a `Property` in Main Model

For example

```
 public class BuyFactor
{
    public int BuyFactorId { get; set; }        
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }        
    public string Seller { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    public decimal SumAllPrice { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BuyFactorDetail> BuyFactorDetails { get; set; }
    public BuyFactorDetail BuyFactorEntity {get;set;}
}
```

Assign value in `BuyFactorEntity` and use as `Model.BuyFactorEntity.BuyFactorDetailId`

Answer (score 0):

Use a Linq join query like

```
    var query = (from b in context.BuyFactors
                     join d in context.BuyFactorDetail
                     on
..
                     select new
                     {
                        BuyFactorId = b.BuyFactorId,
                        ....
                        BuyFactorDetailId = d.BuyFactorDetailId,
                        ...

    ..
                 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your BuyFactor already contains the BuyFactorDetail collection. You sure the entities are 1:N relationship with each other?
You can use the BuyFactor as model and could use the BuyFactorDetails propertu of the BuyFactor entity.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewBag in controller to assign respective objects for both.

```
ViewBag.BuyFactor= BuyFactor;
ViewBab.BuyFactorDetail = BuyFactorDetail;
```

To use it in view you will have to typecast them back.